# Nodejs server: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, heroku, express

I have a web server setted up in node.

```
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(PUBLIC_PATH));
server = require('http').createServer(app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

i set the public path to my app's root public folder, where i keep my frontend, so when the server is deployed, it's */app/public*

When i try to open a page, i see this in chrome's console

> i Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

The file in question is app.js which is located in my *public* folder. I do see requests from the web server for that certain file

> 2015-04-04T15:43:04.208178+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/style.css" host=hive-badescuga.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=2be0334e-e968-4397-8c2e-9c65c85fea22 fwd="188.25.247.211"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=236
>
> 2015-04-04T15:43:04.203415+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/app.js" host=hive-badescuga.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=fc8c529c-7641-4df2-9b13-5fee9e1af365 fwd="188.25.247.211"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=217
>
> 2015-04-04T15:43:09.152566+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/style.css" host=hive-badescuga.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=b89ded8e-5433-4b57-8c80-c2e7407d31b0 fwd="188.25.247.211"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=236

What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

As i'm debugging further i see that a css in the same root as my app.js (that can't be loaded), gets loaded. Here is my html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
```

so style.css does get loaded while app.js doesn't (because it can't be found), and they are in the same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is fixed, had the app.js git ignored so it worked locally but it wasn't uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will help, but may be you should write:
process.env.PUBLIC_PATH. Also, I don't know if you have this:

```
var express = require('express');
```

I have this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname ,'views')));
```

Comment: i've tried process.env.PUBLIC_PATH but it still doesn't work :( yes, i do have express inited.. my PUBLIC_PATH is path.join(__dirname, 'public') so it's good..